# Remove duplicate rows based on previous rows' values in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe similar to the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'col2': [1.55,1.55,1.55,1.8,1.9,1.9,1.9,2.1,2.1]})
```

In the second column, col2, several duplicate values can be seen, 3 times 1.55, 3 times 1.9 and 2 times 2.1. What I need to do is remove all rows which are a duplicate of its previous row. So, the first rows are the ones I'd like to keep. In this example, this would be the rows with col2 value 1, 4, 5, 8 giving the following dataframe as my desired output:

```
clean_data = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,4,5,8], 'col2': [1.55,1.8,1.9,2.1]})
```

What is the best way to go about this for a dataframe which is much larger (in terms of rows) than this small example?

Comment: Do you want to remove rows that are a duplicate of just the immediately previous rows, or rows that are a duplicate of **any** of the previous rows?

Comment: Only of the immediate previous row, not of all previous rows. Sorry for the unclear description.

Comment: Rereading your question, I think your intent is clear; my mistake.

Comment: For posterity: if you want to remove rows where the col2 entry is a duplicate of **any** of the preceding values, you can do `clean_data = data.loc[~data['col2'].duplicated(),:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift`:

```
data.loc[data['col2'] != data['col2'].shift(1)]
```